# Fire Event on Background Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

**Just the background:**
*(not really related to the question)*

I am using SharePoint and creating a Sharepoint Hosted App.

I have some fields which provide a peoplepicker with which I can select Users out of a user pool. The functioninality is provide by the SharePoint internal scripts.

If I input a name of a user via jquery nothing happens. It has no built-in change handler I guess.

What I have done is a separat script which just resolve the user names on my jquery input via `trigger("change")` and then the SharePoint internal Scripts doing the job. This "job" is asynchronous and then if the data arrives from the backend the SharePoint Scripts apply the data to the Peoplepicker fields.

**But this functions also doesn't support jQuery's trigger because I cannot alter the functions as they're pre-defined...**

So want I want to do is to monitor when the text inside the Peoplepicker fields has been changed but I am a little bit lost now.

**Question:**

I have tried it with the following code (which doesn't work):

```
$('.peoplePickerDiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    alert("HAS BEEN CHANGED!");
});
```

Is there another way to react on lets say background editing of input fields in my DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For People Picker control manipulation [`SPClientPeoplePicker object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.aspx) (`clientpeoplepicker.js`) is intended, which provides methods for getting information from the picker or to perform other operation.

`SPClientPeoplePicker` class exposes the following events:

- [`OnControlValidateClientScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.oncontrolvalidateclientscript.aspx) -  triggers  after a server error is set or cleared
- [`OnUserResolvedClientScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.onuserresolvedclientscript.aspx) - triggers once the resolved user is added or removed in client
- [`OnValueChangedClientScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.onvaluechangedclientscript.aspx) - triggers after text input or users change in client

`OnValueChangedClientScript` event probably suits your scenario, here is an example on how to attach it:

```
var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerId];
picker.OnValueChangedClientScript = function (elementId, userInfo) {
    if(userInfo.length > 0){ // once the value is resolved it could be retrieved via `userInfo` object
       console.log(userInfo[0]);   
    }
    console.log('value changed');
};
```

**References**

[Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx)

Comment: A caveat about this method: I recently ran into a timing issue with Microsoft Edge where my script attaching the event handler ran before the people-picker objects had been populated, so the code failed.

Make sure that `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerId]` is initialized before you attach your event handler.